# preg_match: check birthday format dd.mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yy

Tags: php, date, get, preg-match

I want to get the date from string in format: dd.mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yy

My code is:

```
$string = 'My test bla bla bla (21.11.13)'
if(preg_match("/([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2|4})/", $string))
{
echo 'ok';
}
```

But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression with "/" delimiters:

```
/\([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.([0-9]{2})|([0-9]{4})\)/
```

I have taken out the bracket for the day and month assuming that only the whole date is required. Plus if you do not require the surrounding brackets in (21.11.13), remove the backslash-escaped brackets at the start and the end.

Additionally, if you just want to check for the presence of the string, use:

```
$match = preg_match("/\([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.([0-9]{2})|([0-9]{4})\)/", $string);
if($match === 1)
{
  echo 'ok';
}
elseif($match === 0)
{
 echo 'not found';
}
else
{
 echo 'error in regular expression';
}
```